# Mobile safari fixed header

Tags: mobile, safari, scroll, fixed

This is a tricky one because I don't see how I can fix it on a horizontal level.

Here is the site.

http://www.raycollinsphoto.com

On Safari on my iPhone or iPad when I scroll to the right the nav goes with it. However, on desktop browsers it works perfectly.

I have tried some of the viewport fixes but I can only seem to break it more.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll ?

iScroll allows you to simulate a fixed area on a mobile device (since mobile devices do not support the traditional `position:fixed` property).

I hope this helps.